# Adding new VM's to VirtualBox via Mac terminal / usage with Vagrant

Tags: macos

I'm just getting started with using VirtualBox. I'm trying to do all my work GUI free, i.e. only using iTerm2, and want to work with different VM's command terminal's via Vagrant. So my questions are:

1. How or what is the process/command to add different VM's to my VirtualBox that are each using the vagrant feature?
2. When starting vagrant using the command: `vagrant up`, how do i specify which VM i want to use?

I have looked at different explanations, e.g. the vagrant and virtualbox websites, but they seem a bit too specific to a certain case. My employer already setup Debian successfully and it is compatible with vagrant but I am not exactly sure how that was done or what the folder locations mean.